# WCF Hosting with Firebird database connection on Windows 2003 

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I've been developing a WCF Service that access a Firebird database. This Working fine in local machine, but when I tried run at Windows 2003 Datacenter Server don't return a correct value, like do not connected at database.

No error shown!

Thanks!

Web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="AnielTV.Server.AnielTVServiceBehavior" 
                 name="AnielTV.Server.AnielTVService">
           <endpoint 
               address="" behaviorConfiguration="web" 
               binding="webHttpBinding" 
               contract="AnielTV.Server.IAnielTVService">
              <identity>
                  <dns value="localhost"/>
              </identity>
           </endpoint>
           <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" 
                     contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
       <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="web">
             <webHttp/>
          </behavior>
       </endpointBehaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior name="AnielTV.Server.AnielTVServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
           </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: What **binding** are you using? **Show us** some of your **server-side config**!! Without seeing it, it's pure speculation - at best.....

Comment: I have run all of my WCF services on Server 2003. Connecting to databases.

Comment: **[RESOLVED]** The problem was resolved. The Publish resource from Visual Studio didn't upload the Firebird Client DLL. I did manual and work fine.

The reason for that was because DLL was strongly referenced.